# How do i save a single user's daily input separately, so that it can be accessed later on a database?

Tags: database-design

Basically i have built a diary-like website which stores whatever the user types, into a database colomn. i want it to be like an actual diary where the user logs in and writes his thoughts each day, and can later access all pages he has written.

Right now i have just one `diary` colomn in the row of the database allotted one per user. making one table per user would be inefficient.

So how can i store user's input with a date to be accessed later?

colomns in database: `id` (AI, int), `email` (text), `password` (text), `diary`(text), `date` (date).

Comment: I changed the tags, since leaving it in PHP would have highlighted your question for closure.  On SO, you have to ask specific code questions.  See [ask] and [mcve].  The `database-design` tag is more lenient for that, since the design is the topic, not the code to set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup should be normalized.  What I mean:

- Create a table for users.
- Create a table for diary entries.
- The diary table links each entry to one of the users.

Ex.:

```
Table Users
    ID: auto-increment id
    EmailAddress: string
    Password: string

Table diary_entries
    ID: auto-incremnt id
    UserId: foreign key to table Users, ID field
    Entry: the diary entry itself
    Date: the date when the entry was added.  This could be set to NOW() when you do the insert.
```

- This way each diary entry is linked to 1 users, and has a date.
- You can then search per date, per user, per date AND per user.
- If you had kept it all in a single table, you would have had to put in the user's password in every line, for every entry.  How would you know which password is good?
- That is what normalization does, it ensures your database design is not blocking you or creating problems later.  Forms 1, 2 and 3 are the usual forms applied.  The higher ones are more exotic and not always required for a small project.

As to implementing that, you will have to provide some code, do research, and later post a specific question if your research does not help you.  But do not ask "how to" questions, they will get flagged quickly on SO.